# SSDT fails to preview a table with error 0x80004005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-data-tools

I'm getting an unusual one that I cannot find any reference for out there?? Hope some of you have seen this?
I have a number of packages in my project all working fine, using a Project level Connection Manager, to a SQL Server DB.
I am configuring a number of Source to Destination flows in a Data Flow, to import text files into Stage tables.
I configure the Source to connect to the text file and Preview the data no problem.  I add an OLE DB Connection to the DB and select the desired table in the dropdown. I then Click the View Existing Data button and get the following error;

> An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native
>   Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Unspecified error".
>   An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native
>   Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Communication link
>   failure". Error at DFT_Name [TableName [230]]: Failed to open a
>   fastload rowset for TableName. Check that the object exists in the
>   database.

I also get a similar error if I try to Click the Mappings tab.  The Connection Manage is working fine as I have an Execute SQL task in the Control flow that runs fine.

I should mention that in desperation, I deleted all the Data flow tasks and saved the package. I then recreated the data flows and all worked fine. I come in today and the problem is back, although no changes were made!!  This has to be to do with Password caching or some such, but I am using Windows Authentication and the CM tests fine and the Execute SQL task still runs !! Help?

Comment: Based on your last paragraph, sounds like some kind of corruption.   Try deleting and recreating the problem dataflow again.

Comment: This sounds more like SSIS than SSDT?

Comment: Bit of both. I'm working on an SSIS package in SSDT.

Comment: Did you ever track down the cause of this issue?

Comment: I think it was indeed due to corruption, due to using different versions of BIDS/SSDT to edit the same project. Redid the work in BIDS 2010 and all OK !!